# Octave read each line of file to vector

Tags: file, matrix, octave, delimiter

I have a file data.txt

```
1 22 34 -2
3 34 -3
2
3 43 -3 2 3
```

And I want to load this file onto Octave as separate matrices

```
matrix1 = [1; 22; 34 ;-2]
matrix2 = [3; 34 -3]
.
.
.
```

How do I do this? I've tried fopen and fgetl, but it seems as if each character is given its own spot in the matrix. I want to separate the values, not the characters (it's space delimited).

Comment: use the `dlmread` function with `" "` for SEP

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty:

```
A = dlmread("file");

matrix = 1; # just for nice varname generation
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    name = genvarname("matrix",who());
    eval([name " = A(i,:);"]);
    eval(["[_,__," name "] = find(" name ");"]);
end

clear _ __ A matrix i
```

The format needs to be as you specified.